# File I/O end of line

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, while-loop, ifstream

I am trying to read text from a file into an array and then output the contents of each array index to the output file. I need the data to be read/stored until it reaches the end of line, at which point it should re-start reading/storing and re-using the array for temporary storage only to be output to the output file.

I cannot use the getline function because the idea is that later I will incorporate the use of some model classes to store the individual words as member variables of the classes. I will need to have the words separated to know which words get saved as which variables. For this reason I need to be able to just identify the corresponding index position and get it's contents.

I know my syntax is incorrect so I was hoping someone knew a correct syntax for recognizing the end of line.

this is what I've tried so far:

```
ifstream fin;

//open file... 

char next[20]; //creating an word array to hold the characters of a word.      
fin >> next;

while (!fin == '\n')   //<------ THIS IS WHAT I THINK THE PROBLEM IS.
                   //I KNOW ITS INCORRECT BUT DO NOT KNOW THE CORRECT WAY.
{                      
  //input words, store to array, and output to file
  fin >> next;
}
```

Comment: Why bother with arrays? Why you don't just use vectors. Also, it will be helpful if you provide sample for the input and the output of your code.

Comment: I don't see why you cannot use getline. If you want to seperate lines and words then use getline to read in one line, create a stringstream from that line and use it to read the single words.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `std::string` instead of a `char` array to handle words of any size. Streams also have an implicit conversion to `void*` (`bool` in C++11 or later) to test if the stream is still valid.

```
std::ifstream fin(filename);
std::string word;
while(fin >> word) {
    //do something with word
}
```